# Get headers from markdown using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get only `h1` and `h2` headers from markdown file using regex, but unfortunately I don't know regex well and can't write the correct solution.

With this expression I'm near the solution (I think so):
`/\#{1,2} (.*?)(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)/gm`

But it returns also headers with more than two hashes.

Test case:

```
# first \r
## second \r
### third \r## fourth \r
```

This should return `['first', 'second', 'fourth']`

Comment: Does adding `^` at the start solve the problem? `/^#{1,2} (.*?)(\\r\\n|\\r|\\n)/gm`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in that case it solve the problem, but what if everything I have in one line? (I edited a question)

Comment: Then a `(?<!#)` can help, this will fail a position right after a `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```js
/(?<!#)#{1,2} (.*?)(\\r(?:\\n)?|\\n)/gm
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/dVADRK/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #                        '#'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #{1,2}                   '#' (between 1 and 2 times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                           ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    r                        'r'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \\                       '\'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    n                        'n'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
```